# how to download Fetch job application resumes from Faceboook's GraphQL

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing an ATS in Python, that integrates with facebook job postings, the facebook messages which are accessible via the /conversations graphql api include the person's fbid and their name and an attachment field, however, it is unclear if it is possible or not to actually download the attachments, which is a "rich card" with the candidate's contact details.

I'm reading this docs, but also I'm a newbie regarding GraphQL, so I'm unsure as to how to actually download the attachments. 
surfing the web didn't yield results.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/message/attachments

how to download Fetch job application resumes  from Faceboook's GraphQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately downloading attachments from the GraphQL API its still not supported as stated on this thread: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/153137724878722?browse=external_tasks_search_results_52517d949d48d3494815922

Comment: Thank you, random stranger on the internet!